# How to ship an app that uses a C++ library via CLI?

Tags: c++

I’ve got an app that creates a child process to execute via CLI a compiled C++ library file. What is the best/most portable way of shipping my app with this library? I just need to ensure the compiled C++ code is available on the user’s system and that the executable is compatible with their system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is compiled for each platform (Windows, macOs, Linux). So you need three different distributions:

1. Windows - lowest common version (for example Windows 7). You also need to require or include the C++ redistributable for the compiled library.
2. Linux - most use gcc, so again the lowest common version. No redistributable required.
3. macOs is similar to Linux.

Each platform supports multiple compilers and IDEs. It’s down to personal choice.